# google plus api : followers' list of a page (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

Are there any solutions that I get a list of followers (and their IDs) of a certain page that I'm managing ? (a page created by my account, different from my account's page)

Tried gapi.client.plus.people.list method with userId replaced by the page's ID, it returns the message 'undefined'. (used 'visible' as collection parameter)

If I use same method with my account ID, it returns the list of people that I added to any of my circles.

Any solutions?

Comment: + if not possible in javascript, is there any language that is capable of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not generally available. There is an API for page management which has this functionality (https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup), but it is only available for larger page management systems unfortunately.